# web Api 2 mobile authenticaton

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a server in Web API2 , with Owin bearer authentication token.

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

**How can I consume / enable that for Mobile Native App use Web API2 service to authenticate.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To register a user:

```
Send a POST request to /api/account/register with:
header: Content-Type: application/json
body: { 'UserName': 'xxx', 'Password': 'yyy', 'ConfirmPassword': 'yyy' }
```

Now that you have a registered user, you have to 'log them in' and get a token back that you will use with each subsequent request to identify the user making the request:

```
Send a POST request to /token with:
header Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
body: { grant_type=password&username=Alice&password=password123 }
```

That will return JSON similar to this:

```
{
    'access_token':'boQtj0SCGz2GFGz,
    'token_type':'bearer',
    'expires_in':1209599,
    'userName':'xxx',
    '.issued":'Mon, 14 Oct 2013 06:53:32 GMT',
    '.expires":'Mon, 28 Oct 2013 06:53:32 GMT'
}
```

That access token is what you need to identify the user making a request so store it somewhere. When you make another request as the user 'xxx', you need to include that token as a header like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer boQtj0SCGz2GFGz
```

Note that the token will be much longer. That's all there is to it. Each time you make a request you just need to include the token as a header.

[I found this info here. It's a good read.](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: But  Jquery not sending Authorization Request to Service failing with status cancelled

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: To Login User - How can I pass credentials to Web Api Server from Native Mobile Application

Comment: I edited my answer to explain in much more depth. I haven't done any mobile development so you'll need to look into how to make http requests and parse the returned json with whatever platform you're developing for. It should be pretty easy though.